# Hot to use variable in query in Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal-8

I have this code:

```
function my_module_test($key_make = '') {
  $db = new mysqli('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', "xxx");
  mysqli_set_charset($db, "UTF8");
  if ($key_make) {
    $sql_model = "SELECT * FROM `car_model` WHERE `id_car_make` = ('$key_make')";
    $res_model = $db->query($sql_model) or die(mysqli_error($db));
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($res_model)) {
      $Key_model = $row->id_car_model;
      $Model_value = $row->name;

      $dropdown_model[$Key_model] = $Model_value;
    }
  }
  return $dropdown_model;
}
```

How can I pass the value of the variable $key_make in WHERE clausole ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to use the Drupal Database API to connect to a database. So my final code is the following and it works.

```
function car2db_model_dropdown_options($key_make) {
  $connection = Database::getConnection('default', 'migrate');
  $dropdown_model = ['_none'=>'Select'];
  $key_make = (int)$key_make;

  $sql_model = "SELECT * FROM car_model WHERE id_car_make = :make";
  $query = $connection->query($sql_model, [':make' => $key_make]);
  $result = $query->fetchAll();

  foreach ($result as $row) {
    $Key_model = $row->id_car_model;
    $Model_value = $row->name;

    $dropdown_model[$Key_model] = $Model_value;
  }
  return $dropdown_model;
}
```

Comment: A little off topic, but where did you get you list of car makes and models? I am going to need a list for an upcoming project.

Comment: To car2db.com. I managed to create the dynamic dropdown but when I go to save it returns the error: "An illegal choice is detected ...."

Comment: When / where are you running your code to set the dropdown options? You need to set them while the form is being built otherwise you will get the error you are seeing. It is a security feature of drupal forms to stop people from being able to send any option value they want.

Comment: I have asked question here: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60662918/an-illegal-choice-is-detected-error-with-dynamic-dropdown-select-list-i-dru[link] with code

Comment: Please accept the answer here if it did indeed answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

The query function takes a second parameter with an array of replacement values, so you would do it like this:

```
$sql_model = "SELECT * FROM {car_model} WHERE id_car_make = :make";
$res_model = $db->query($sql_model, [':make' => $key_make]);
```

Static queries are [documented here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/database-api/static-queries)

You could also use a dynamic query ([documented here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/database-api/dynamic-queries/introduction-to-dynamic-queries)):

```
$query = $db->select('car_model', 'cm');
$query->fields('cm');
$query->condition('cm.id_car_make', $key_make);
$res_model = $query->execute();
```

**But**...
if your "car_model"s are custom entities (which they should be as you will get many benefits like views integration), you should probably use an [entityQuery](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AentityQuery/8.2.x)